# Porquê match retorna um objeto - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Sempre fui daqueles que entendia as funções e apliquei, mas quero entender, porquê isso:

```js
var a = "__myseld=ej232;Nome=Alexandre";
var as = a.split(";");
var x = 0;
while (x<5) {
    alert("type of de as(sem match): " + typeof(as[x]));
    bs = as[x].match(/a/i);
    alert("typeof de bs(match): " + typeof(bs));
    if (as[x].match(/nome/i) != null){
        
        alert("achei!: " + as[x]);
        x=6;
    }
    else {
     x+=1;   
    }
}
```

Qual moral de uma função retornar um objeto? Existe uma justificativa para essa aplicação? ME ajude a entender um pouco esse conceito de objeto em javascript, entendo que objeto é uma instância de uma classe, com isso ele recebe propriedades da classe que nele foi instanciada..
Se quiser receitar um lugar para ler mais sobre isso, agradeço também!

Comment: Bom, antes de mais nada recomendo ler esse artigo do W3C: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: Para completar o comentário do Marcelo. O método [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) retorna um `Array` (pois podem existir múltiplos resultados). Um `Array` é um objeto.

Comment: rsrs, é doido isso, um Array é na sua essência um objeto que pode ou não conter vários outros objetos de diferentes tipos.

Comment: Boa tarde, alguma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema? Se sim por favor marque-a como "Correta". Se não diga o que falta. Grato.

Comment: Sim, há varias perguntas que sempre acabo esquecendo de marcar como melhor resposta.. Mas vou tentar ir corrigindo isso, obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em JavaScript tanto objectos como arrays (entre outros) são... objectos. Este assunto tem sido debatido bastante, e principalmente porque é muitas vezes importante distinguir exatamente entre array e objetos (estou a referir-me a Tipo *Object* e Tipo *Array*).

Isto é na verdade uma parte da linguagem que é "incompleta". Para completar esta falha, na versão 5 da EcmaScript, foi implementado um novo método para ajudar a esta destinção: [`Array.isArray(var)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Este novo método, disponivel em browsers modernos (IE9+) permite tirar as dúvidas. Ou seja:

```
Array.isArray({}) // false
Array.isArray([]) // true
```

Antes de isto ser possivel havia maneiras diferentes, mais trabalhosas, de chegar á mesma conclusão. Uma delas está sugerida na MDN como Polyfil. Juntando este código ele detecta se o browser suporta o `.isArray()` e adiciona o método a *Array* caso necessário:

```
if (!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function(arg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
  };
}
```

No fundo um objeto é *Array* se o seguinte fôr verdadeiro:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]'
```

A moral de uma função/método retornar um objeto é porque Arrays e Objetos em JavaScript são instâncias de *Object*. Isto é mais ou menos como a gramática, é preciso aprender e aceitar que é assim :)

Exemplo (e outra maneira de distinguir Arrays de Objetos):

```
var a = [];
var o = {};
a instanceof Array   // true
o instanceof Array   // false <---

a instanceof Object  // true
o instanceof Object  // true
```

Answer (score 1):

`.match` pode retornar tanto `Array` quanto `null` e ambos são "considerados" `object` pelo Javascript, na linha:

```
 bs = as[x].match(/a/i);
```

retorna `null` no primeiro loop e `array` no segundo, `typeof` vai informar que ambos são `object`.

Para verificar se um `object` é um `array`, você pode fazer isto:

```
if (bs instanceof Array) {
    //Seu código
}
```

Um teste:

```js
var a = "__myseld=ej232;Nome=Alexandre";
var as = a.split(";");
var x = 0;
while (x<5) {
    alert("type of de as(sem match): " + typeof(as[x]));
    bs = as[x].match(/a/i);

    if (bs instanceof Array) {
        alert("bs é array");
        console.log(bs);
    } else if (bs === null) {
        alert("bs é NULL");
    }

    if (as[x].match(/nome/i) != null){
        
        alert("achei!: " + as[x]);
        x=6;
    }
    else {
     x+=1;   
    }
}
```